# Cannot login in Wordpress even after changing hash password in phpmyadmin

Tags: wp-admin, users, login, woocommerce-offtopic, password

An hour ago I changed the password of my Head Admin user. But after this I was not able to login anymore. So I have tried to reset the password in PHPmyadmin with the md5 encoding and even with this Wordpress hasher http://scriptserver.mainframe8.com/wordpress_password_hasher.php, but it does not work anymore.

I also tried other accounts, but they cannot login as well. The last thing I have tried is to use the new password function in the wordpress login screen, and also this does not work.

Does anyone have an idea what I need to do? Is the emergency reset script of Wordpress an option? https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Comment: might sound stupid, but are you sure that you changing the password for the right site

Comment: Have you tried to using the "Forgot password" in WordPress login? Are you sure, you are modifying in the right database?

Comment: Yes I had tried that function. I solved the problem with changing the password with the FTP option from the Wordpress codex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the `wp_set_password();` function as the [emergency reset script documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password) of Wordpress explains, which helped me to set a new password for my admin account.